# Android Beacon Library - didEnterRegion not firing when app in background or stopped for pre-Android 8

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

First some background:

My setup uses a Service, which implements `BeaconConsumer` and binds to the `BeaconManager`. I have additional handling so when my app leaves the foreground, I move my Service to run in foreground, and when my app enters the foreground, I move my Service to run in background. That way, the persistent notification should display if and only if the app isn't displaying. In accordance, I am using the pattern [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html) to tell `BeaconManager` I'm running this Service in the foreground, to allow for more frequent scanning. The link above isn't quite clear about this, but I believe this pattern should work without alterations needed on both pre-Android 8 as well as Android 8+. It shouldn't be strictly necessary on pre-Android 8, since the OS is more lenient. However, using this setup across all versions has the collateral benefit of ensuring that the OS does not kill the Service. If the app is in the foreground, the Service is background but has priority by virtue of the app, and if the app is not in the foreground, the Service is, and therefore has priority.

Now the problem: On pre-Android 8 devices, my Service is not seeing didEnterRegion called when the app is not in the foreground (but the Service is). It works fine on Android 8+.

some code snippets:

In my Service, set up the BeaconManager, set scan intervals

```
_beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
                _beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                        setBeaconLayout(IBEACON_PATTERN_1));
                _beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
                _beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
                _beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);
```

Function in my Service I invoke to send the service to the foreground, and background:

```
private void sendServiceToForeground() {
    this.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, _notification);

    if (_beaconManager != null) {
        if (_beaconManager.isBound(this)) {
            _beaconManager.unbind(this);
        }
        _beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(_notification, NOTIFICATION_ID);
        _beaconManager.bind(this);
    }
}


private void sendServiceToBackground() {

    if (_beaconManager != null) {
        if (_beaconManager.isBound(this)) {
            _beaconManager.unbind(this);
        }
        _beaconManager.disableForegroundServiceScanning();
        _beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    this.stopForeground(true);
}
```

I can provide more code as requested. Not sure what all is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to unbind() and bind() are asynchronous, so calling them one after another will be a problem unless you first wait for the unbind() operation to complete.  This is tricky, because the library's BeaconManager does not provide a callback to tell you when unbind is complete (indeed, this is because the underlying Android service APIs also do not provide such a callback.  You essentially don't know when the library's scanning service has stopped so you can safely restart it again in a different mode.)

It's a bit of a hack, but you might try adding a delay between unbind() and bind() to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: OK, I will give it a try. How long is a good time to delay, 5 seconds? (Also, bonus question, what is the right Java/Android thing to call to accomplish this?)

Comment: 5 sec should be more than enough.  For delays, check out `handler.postDelayed`

Comment: I think the problem is introduced by trying to achieve this:

"I have additional handling so when my app leaves the foreground, I move my Service to run in foreground, and when my app enters the foreground, I move my Service to run in background. That way, the persistent notification should display if and only if the app isn't displaying."

With that workaround, I fear I'll be introducing a bunch of race conditions if the user homes in and out of the app repeatedly. When I get rid of this behavior and just always run the service in the foreground, the problem goes away. <continued>

Comment: <continued from last comment> So I'll probably just get rid of that behavior in my app - it'd be nice to have but not a must. We'd always run the service in the foreground. It seems like the BeaconManager is not intended to be bound to/unbound from repeatedly like this.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, as far as I can tell this answer can't be what the problem is, as (enable|disable)ForegroundServiceScanning throw an exception if the beaconManager is still bound, and in my executions they aren't throwing an exception, which means the unbind process is completing before this call.

Comment: I know others have been able to accomplish this same thing.  It's hard to comment further without at least seeing logs.of what is happening in your bind/unbind process.  If you want to try to get this working, I'd suggest setting `beaconManager.setDebug(true);` then capturing a log that covers the time where you unbind/bind then fail to detect.